# SyntaxError: Left hand side of operator '=' must be a reference

Tags: javascript, reference, syntax-error, underscore.js, operator-keyword

I hope someone could help as I have no clue on how to proceed with this error.

I am in the process of upgrading my existing site. My temp new site, [tempsite](https://www.emjwebsitedesign.com/proposed/emj_marketing/), and plugins were all working fine until I upgraded to Wordpress 5.2.2–en_CA.

Now I get the following error :

```
 `SyntaxError: Left hand side of operator '=' must be a reference`
```

Here is the instance code for the mini calendar.

```
<div class="clndr-controls">
    <div class="current-month"><%= month %> <%= year %></div>
    <div class="clndr-nav clndr-clearfix">
        <div class="clndr-previous-button">‹</div>
        <div class="clndr-next-button">›</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clndr-grid">
    <div class="days-of-the-week clndr-clearfix">
        <% _.each(daysOfTheWeek, function(day) { %>
        <div class="header-day"><%= day %></div>
        <% }); %>
    </div>
    <div class="days clndr-clearfix">
        <% _.each(days, function(day) { %>
        <div class="<%= day.classes %>" id="<%= day.id %>"><span class="day-number"><%= day.day %></span></div>
    <% }); %>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="event-listing">
    <div class="event-listing-title">Events</div>
    <% _.each(eventsThisMonth, function(event) { %>
        <% if (event.url) {  %><a target="<%= event.url_target %>" href="<%= event.url %>" <% } else {  %><div <% }  %> class="event-item clndr-clearfix">
        <span class="event-item-date">
            <% if (event.end != event.start) {
                startMY = moment(event.start).format("MM YY");
                endMY = moment(event.end).format("MM YY");
                if (startMY === endMY) { %>
                    <%= moment(event.start).format("D") %>–<%= moment(event.end).format("D MMMM") %>
                <% } else { %>
                    <%= moment(event.start).format("D MMMM") %> – <%= moment(event.end).format("D MMMM") %>
                    <% } 
                 } else {  %>
                    <%= moment(event.start).format("D MMMM") %>
                <% } %>
            </span>
            <span class="event-item-name"><%= event.title %></span>
            <% if (event.time) {  %>
                <span class="event-item-time"><%= event.time %></span>
            <% } %>
            <% if (event.location){ %>
                <span class="event-item-time"><%= event.location %></span>
            <% } %>
            <span class="event-item-time">With: <%= event.speaker %></span>
            <span class="event-item-desc"><%= event.desc %></span>
        <% if (event.url) {  %></a><% } else {  %></div><% }  %>
    <% }); %>
</div>
```

Here is the js object options

```
doneRendering: function() {
    var day=1, week=1, thisCLNDR = $(this)[0]["element"];
    //make the background rows alternate colour
    thisCLNDR.find(".day").each(function() {
        if (day == 8) { day = 1; week++; }
        if (week % 2 === 0) { $(this).addClass("alternate-bg"); }
        day++;
});
//display a notice if there are no events for a month
var thisMonthEvents = thisCLNDR.find(".event-item").length;
if (thisMonthEvents == 0) {
    thisCLNDR.find(".event-listing").append(
        "<div style='text-align:center;' class='event-item'>No events found</div>"
        );
    }
},
weekOffset: 1
```

[image]

Comment: I guess I should say that the plugin,event-CLNDR, that is not working is a mini calendar at the bottom of the page in the footer. The calendar should show up above the link-"View main calendar - here".  The main calendar works fine.

Comment: Please post the code that does not work.

Comment: where I think it is breaking is between the plugin, CLNDR.min.js and underscore.js.  I can't post all the code for the CLNDR.min.js it is to large and i am not sure how to add a file

Comment: Can you break it down to a [mcve] maybe? Looks like only line 82 (the `init` function) is relevant.

Comment: Here is a link to CLNDR.min.js  [link]https://github.com/kylestetz/CLNDR/blob/master/clndr.min.js[/link]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code with syntax highlighting, then delete your comments.

Comment: Probably it's `<% =` instead of `<%=` somewhere

Comment: I tried editing those and  I get the following error:

    `unexpected token: '='`

What is weird is the code for the "Full Calendar", which works fine, and the "Mini Calendar" is exactly the same but the Mini Calendar get the error.

Comment: Hm, when I pass the code you posted to `_.template`, I don't get an error.

Comment: I downgraded to Wordpress version 5.1.1 and I don't have the issue.

Comment: What changed in the code when doing that?

Comment: I assumed it would have been a different version of jquery or underscore.js but I compared version 5.1.1 to 5.2.2 and they are the same.